# Is this well designed? Are these parameters applied correctly?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Lately I've been designing a simulator of animal life, and ended up running into some design problems. I'll try to sum ​​it up as best as possible, pointing out only the necessary (I think).

### THE PROBLEM

I'm trying to make living beings have the ability to reproduce. However, there are beings that reproduce sexually, and that reproduce asexually.

With the desire to keep the design dynamic and flexible following the [open/close princible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), I decided to use the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), and I ended up with the following situation:

[image]

Despite the ability of creating different types of reproduction, with each type having its own algorithm, the type of sexual reproduction requires a parameter, which would be another LivingBeing.

Researching the internet, I discovered that the strategy pattern can be modified to make use of the types of parameters that are extendible. With that in mind, I decided to create a parameter to the method reproduce existing on ReproduceBehavior. Here's what I got:

[image]

### THE QUESTION

My real doubts are about the implementation of different types of reproduction parameters.

Even if I create a parameter to sexual reproduction, it is meaningless to asexual reproduction, right? For what reason I'm giving a parameter to asexual reproduction? If you tell me it's okay, and that this is acceptable as long as I just disregard this parameter in the implementation of the method, then fine.

So, how can I implement the parameter of sexual reproduction? Should I create a concrete class named *SexualParameter* where it implements the interface *ReproductionParameter*? Plus, how can I make *SexualReproduction* to recognize that it's *ReproductionParameter* is a *SexualParameter*? Should I use *instanceof*? Does That would be correct (best practice)?

I'm really confused about it. Could anyone help me?

### EDIT

Due to the vows of my companions for closing my question, I'm editing it so that it is more restricted, and has specific criteria to be solved. So here we go...

We're talking about reproduction, correct? And I cannot simply mimic in a simulator the real life (for now, I belive...), but I can get close to such a situation (without exaggeration). So I am exposing and better defining the criteria for reproduction here:

1. All living beings reproduces.
2. There are beings that reproduce one of the following 3 ways: Sexual, Asexual, and both ways.
3. All being has a gender. The genders are Male, or Female (gay animals cannot reproduce, sorry).
4. Females copulate with males, and vice versa.
5. All living beings can produce 0, 1, or several children during
   the act.
6. Different living beings possess reproduction criteria. If accepted,
   a reproduction is successfully committed.
7. A living being can only reproduce with another of the same type.

I will accept any kind of design that satisfies these rules. The first answer that can satisfy these conditions, will be taken as correct for me. If you will be based on what we've talked here or not does not matter... As I said, it is only necessary to satisfy these rules.

### EDIT 2

To be frank, there is a set of rules and standards that can be used for a good design to be done. One thing for sure has already been proven here. Code reuse is key in any design. This can be done in different ways, one of which is using inheritance. When inheritance ends up hurting reuse, is a fact that it should not be used.

For my fellow programmers, do not view the project design as something based on opinion as well. The project design is something serious and concrete. Nobody creates a code snippet based on it's own opinion. This reminds me of the [Entity Relationship Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) (ERM). It is an exact science, what changes are only the cases, not the way to which we apply the modeling based on the rules of each one. Similarly, class modeling is not an opinion based thing. Does moderators veterans here are just wandering without direction? Sometimes I regret not knowing certain things.

Comment: personally, I don't like the idea of a useless parameter, in the case of asexual reproduction. Instead, I'd add a constructor to SexualReproduction that would required a non-null LivingBeing and keep both reproduce() methods without any parameters.

Comment: I had thought this hypothesis before searching the internet. I think this situation is correct. I was in doubt after research on the internet, so I tried another approach. Could you tell me if this type of approach is applicable and maintainable (with sources)?

Comment: Another approach is to remove the "ReproductionBehaviour" interface (I think there are some species that have both Sexual and Asexual Reproductions). This way you could just add the partner as a parameter to the SexualReproduction interface. This seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: Please, I ask you (moderators) to not close my question, because I think I finally found the solution and I would like to share with everyone.

Comment: sorry, this is beyond my powers.

Comment: Hi Leo! I would like to share with you my diagram. Unfortunately, this system does not allow me to send you private messages. How can I contact you?

Comment: my profile has my contact info. you can send me an email in portuguese if you wish ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think "ReproductionBehaviour" is somewhat unnatural in a sense that some species may have both Sexual and Asexual reproduction behaviours (although, I understand every species need to have at least one reproduction method).

This is how I'd model

```
interface SexualReproduction<T extends LivingBeing>{
    void reproduce(T partner);
}

interface AsexualReproduction{
    void reproduce();
}

abstract class LivingBeing{

}

class Cat extends LivingBeing implements SexualReproduction<Cat>{

    @Override
    public void reproduce(Cat partner) {

    }
}

class Bacteria extends LivingBeing implements AsexualReproduction{

    @Override
    public void reproduce() {
    }

}

class Starfish extends LivingBeing implements AsexualReproduction,SexualReproduction<Starfish>{

    @Override
    public void reproduce(Starfish partner) {

    }

    @Override
    public void reproduce() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Your approach makes sense. However, does that not result in code duplication? I omitted part of my diagram, but the rules of reproduction are very similar between (at least) mammals. Say the code checks sexuality, temperature, if the LivingBeing is sterile, among other things, and then pah! A new LivingBeing is generated. Of course not all reproduce the same way, but I end up with duplicated code, right?

Comment: You can avoid duplicated code by inheritance (using abstract classes that implement the interfaces and make each LivingBeing extends it) or by composition (grouping common code into external classes). Although composition is generally widely recommended over inheritance, just because you're dealing with a species tree, inheritance maybe could fit better in this case. (of course, if we're going to be more strict and go into NCBI species codes, we'll end up figuring out that reproduction is far more complicate in the real world :-) )

Comment: For example, you could create a Mammal abstract class that implements SexualReproduction (with some default Mammal SexualReproduction method implemented) and make Cat extend from Mammal instead of LivingBeing

Comment: This also makes a lot of sense. But how would you name the beings that possess both means of reproduction? The starfish, for example, would fit on what type (unfortunately now we're talking about biology)?

Comment: It depends on what taxonomy you want to use :-) Mammal is from one type. If you want to classify by kingdoms/phylum, than a starfish is Echinodermata. But if you want to find a name just to group both Sexual and Asexual interfaces, I don't think it's a good idea, just because the language will allow you to implement both this new interface plus the SexualReproduction and AsexualReproduction, and we'd lose the flexibility and potentially we'd add an unnecessary mess to the design.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful. I thank you so much for this, especially for being so patient. But see... According to the principles of OOP, inheritance should be used only when all its subtypes share the same characteristics and/or behaviors. The animals that are classified as mammals are not the only ones that reproduce sexually. There are animals that belong to the class Reptilia (such as the snake, turtle, alligator) which are also beings that reproduce sexually. For each class of existing animals, I would have to implement the SexualReproduction interface, which is a bad practice. :/

Comment: You're right. In my defense, I'd say in the real world, you'll seldom have a well defined hierarchy. Having a flexible design sometimes is better than trying to fit all the cases into the diagram :-) cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would back up a few steps and ask, "How is this going to be used?" The answer is the *caller* will need to know if the `LivingBeing` is sexual or asexual already. Because they will need to know to pass in a `ReproductionPartner`, right? Or if it should be a null parameter. So I'm not sure it makes a ton of sense for `SexualReproduction` and `AsexualReproduction` to be based on a common interface. It only really works if the calling code can interchange them without caring which interface is actually being used. [This is the L is SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

So you probably don't want the extra parameter. This means either having the `LivingBeing` to be smart enough to know who they are to reproduce with already (which means you probably want a subclass or interface for `LivingBeing`), or ditch the idea of the common `ReproductiveBehavior`.